# Least Privilege for SQL Agent to run DISKPART

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

The DISKPART script

```
SELECT DISK 1
ONLINE DISK
```

runs fine as long as SQL Agent has admin rights on the server; otherwise the script fails with this message:

```
Message
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.3.9600

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: FOO

DiskPart has encountered an error: Access is denied.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

Initially working through this issue there were errors in the event viewer.  However, now that I have used `dcomcnfg.exe` to give `Full` configuration, `Local Access`, `Local Launch` and `Local Activation` rights for the SQL Agent account to `Virtual Disk Service`, there are no messages showing in the system log -- just the above message in the SQL Agent job history.  I'm looking for the master tome of Windows configuration but there does not seem to be one. Do I need to set up auditing or traces to see what privileges are being requested?

Comment: What happens if you give the SQL agent full access to diskpart in C:\Windows\System32\Diskpart.exe ?

Comment: File permissions, Sebastian?  On my 2012 build, "Users" is getting full control on Diskpart.exe, so that is where I'm at now.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting deep into internals here

> Membership in the local Administrators group, or equivalent, is the
>   [minimum required to run DiskPart](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770877.aspx)

And [this SE thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411710/allow-non-administrators-to-use-diskpart-to-mount-vhds) points to the same.

Now usually you want to avoid giving to much permission to the service accounts and I'm not certain if giving the SQL Server agent permissions to mount/unmount volumes and at the same time delete them would be considered best practices.

You can probably program a system service that can do the diskpart magic and call that but this really ask the question why you would want to to this from SQL Server.

Comment: Spörri, word from someone who worked at Microsoft is good evidence. Do you think a SQL Server credential would allow me to at least reduce the scope of the privilege grant?  That way other jobs run by SQL Agent would not be as `administrator`.  Or would it be better to use a cron job?  I am running a SQL backup to the volume and then dismounting it, so I need it all in one job.

Comment: You might be able to setup a CMD proxy account with a credential with higher privileges and use that to run the job step that unmounts. Or use the windows task scheduler to mount the drive, connect the the database engine using sqlcmd and run the backups and unmount. Or even skip the mount/dismount part and set strict access lists on the backup drive.